# Formula for Recursive Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

My problem is to find the explicit formula for $s_n$ with this recursive rule, here it is:

$s_0 = 1$
$s_1 = 1$

$s_n = (t * s_{n-1})+(e * s_{n-2})$
Where $t$ and $e$ are two constants less than one.

So to be specific, I'm asking for an explicit formula for the $n$th term which has $t$ and $e$ somewhere in it, so I can adjust those to adjust the output.

On a semi-related note, for $t = 0.5, e = 0.1$, the sequence has an interesting similarity to the Fibonacci sequence in reverse. That is, when you add $s_n$ and $s_{n-1}$, for lower values of $n$ the value is very close to $s_{n-2}$. I'm wondering if there is any possible value of $t$ and $e$ that would make this relation exact.

Also, I'm curious if there are any values of $t$ and $e$ for which the sum of the sequence converges.

Comment: Your recurrence has the solution of the form $$s_n = c_1 r_1^n + c_2  r_2^n$$ where $r_1,r_2$ are roots of $$r^2 - tr - e = 0$$ and $c_1,c_2$ are constants which can be found by $s_0 = s_1 = 1$.

Comment: This doesn't work for at least $t = 0.5, e = 0.1$

Comment: It does work.  Why do you think it doesnt? You'll get  $$\frac{1}{26} \left((13 - 3 \sqrt{65}) ((1/20) (5 - \sqrt{65})\right)^n + \left((1/20) (5 + \sqrt{65}))^n (13 + 3 \sqrt{65})\right)$$

Comment: I just tried it in GeoGebra and f(2) gives me 0.45 when it should give me 0.6 or 0.4...

Comment: It gives you indeed $s(2) = 0.6$. See this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F26+%28%2813+-+3+sqrt%2865%29%29+%281%2F20+%285+-+sqrt%2865%29%29%29%5En+%2B+%281%2F20+%285+%2B+sqrt%2865%29%29%29%5En+%2813+%2B+3+sqrt%2865%29%29%29+for+n+%3D+2

Comment: What did I set up wrong here https://imgur.com/a/6whf0VI

Comment: In your input you didn't find the constant $c_1$ and $c_2$ first,  but instead just $f(n) = r_1^n + r_2^n$.

Comment: How do i find those? I thought you said they were 1 because $s_0$ & $s_1$ were 1

Comment: By setting $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ of course.  You get the system \begin{align*} 1 &= c_1 + c_2 \\1 &= c_1 r_1 + c_2 r_2\end{align*} now solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$

Answer (score -1):

This is jus a [linear recurrence relation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/) with corresponding characteristic equation $$r^2 - tr - e = 0.$$